# Replacing words in text using dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that replaces word from a string.

```
ColorPairs = {'red':'blue','blue':'red'}

def ColorSwap(text):
    for key in ColorPairs:
        text = text.replace(key, ColorPairs[key])
    print text

ColorSwap('The red and blue ball')
# 'The blue and blue ball'
instead of
# 'The blue and red ball'
```

This program replaces 'red' to 'blue', but not 'blue' to 'red'.I am stuck trying to figure out a way to make it so that the program doesn't override the first replaced key.

Comment: Do you only want the first replacement? Or do you want to make all replacements that don't undo an earlier replacement?

Comment: unclear for me. Could you provide a long example along with expected output?

Comment: I voted to reopen, it seems that answers in suggested link offer variations of the OPs original idea, and do not answer the question.

Comment: You could do this: 1) convert "red" to "999999" (some temp pattern), 2) convert "blue" to "red" 3) convert "999999" to "blue".

Comment: I appreciate your help, but surely there must be a better way to do this? It would be a hassle if I want to expand my dictionary beside red and blue.

Comment: I think there has to be a better method as well, unfortunately I am not aware of it. That was just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway Akavall, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `re.sub` function.

```
import re
ColorPairs = {'red':'blue','blue':'red'}
def ColorSwap(text):
    print(re.sub(r'\S+', lambda m: ColorPairs.get(m.group(), m.group()) , text))

ColorSwap('The blue red ball')
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. You could use `\w+` instead of `\S+` also. Here for each single match, python would check for the match against the dictionary key. If there is a key like the match then it would replace the key in the string with the value of that particular key.

If there is no key found, it would display `KeyError`  if you use `ColorPairs[m.group()]`. So that i used  `dict.get()` method which returns a default value if there is no key found.

**Output:**

```
The red blue ball
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash, but I don't quite understand what you're using there. Is it possible to do this without importing anything? I am very new at this and your code seems really complicated. Nevertheless I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Kidd see my answer if you don't want to import anything or if you don't want to use regex.

Comment: @Avinash I liked your answer. Great !

Comment: Good answer. This has the advantage that it will work with any amount of inter-word whitespace, and will preserve that whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dictionary is unordered, So It may take `blue` converted to `red` in the first iteration and in the second iteration it change again from `red` to `blue`. So in order to get the result you need to code in this manner. This is certainly not the best Solution but an alternate way.

```
import re
def ColorSwap(text):
    text = re.sub('\sred\s',' blue_temp ', text)
    text = re.sub('\sblue\s', ' red_temp ', text)
    text = re.sub('_temp','', text)
    return text

print ColorSwap('The red and blue ball')
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: It is certainly not the duplicate of multiple replacement. Please remove the tag of `marked as duplicate`.

Comment: I still don't understand, this didn't fix anything. Please see my new edited post. sorry and thanks for helping me.

Comment: @kvivek Try "The blue red ball" as input and yes, this question is actually a duplicate of the question which I linked. Try the top voted answer in that question and the same can be used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex as suggested by @Avinash, you can split `text` into words, replace and then join.

```
ColorPairs = {'red':'blue','blue':'red'}
def ColorSwap(text):
    textList = text.split(' ')
    text = ' '.join(ColorPairs.get(k, k) for k in textList)
    print text

ColorSwap('The red and blue ball')
```

#### output

```
The blue and red ball
```